# If statement with multiple actions return in R does not return what expected?

Tags: r

I built my function like this:

```
my_fun <- function(x){
     u <- runif(4,0,1)
     x <- matrix(0,4,4)
     for (i in 1:4){
          if (u[i]< 0.7){
               x[1] <- u[1]*2
               x[2] <- x[1]*4
               x[3] <- x[2]*x[1]
               x[4] <- x[3]
          }else{
               x[1] <- u[1]*1
               x[2] <- x[1]*3
               x[3] <- x[2]*x[1]
               x[4] <- x[3]
          }
     }
     x
}
```

Then my function return this:

```
> my_fun(3)
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.4207944    0    0    0
[2,] 1.2623833    0    0    0
[3,] 0.5312038    0    0    0
[4,] 0.5312038    0    0    0
```

I would like my function to return values which indicates which values come from < 0.7 and which one from < 0.3. It seems my function only clculate the first condition. Any help please? I store the values in matrix.

Comment: What is your expected output? x[1] is the upper right entry; x[1] ... x[4] are just the first column. If you're wanting to populate the other columns of x you'll need to tell your function to do so.

Comment: `x` has to dimensions, rows and columns. If you want to store each result in columns, you need to increment the column each time through the loop, `x[1, i] <- u[i] * 2; x[2, i] <- x[1, i] * 4;` etc.

Comment: @Gregor your are correct that what I want. Could you please make it as answer so I can then accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` has to dimensions, rows and columns. If you want to store each result in columns, you need to increment the column each time through the loop,

```
x[1, i] <- u[i] * 2
x[2, i] <- x[1, i] * 4
# etc.
```